# ulimit to limit process memory usage

Tags: memory-usage, ulimit

I tried

```
ulimit 1280000 s1-agent
```

but the process still uses more than that. What did I do wrong? Is there a way to limit it in limits.conf? What line should I put in limits.conf do do so?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 or newer, [`ulimit` is a deprecated function](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man3/ulimit.3.html).  You will probably want to [look at `setrlimit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man2/setrlimit.2.html) and it’s accompanying functions. Be warned, though, using these functions without first having a very good understanding of the daemons/processes you’re limiting may have unintended consequences, such as system instability and early process termination.

[Read the docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man2/setrlimit.2.html), verify your settings, and make changes slowly